# not showinf models value in html template django

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-templates

I just created a one app in which i created a db named as Quizz.
User come and give a test on website.
The answers and username get saved in db columns.
Not able to show this table info in html page

**html page**

```
{% for post in data %}
             {{Quizz.ans1}}
        {% endfor %}
```

**views.py**

```
def test(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        user = request.user
        ans1=request.POST['sky']
        ans2=request.POST['cricket']
        ans3=request.POST['river']
        x=Quizz.objects.create(user=user,ans1=ans1,ans2=ans2,ans3=ans3)
        x.save()
        return redirect('home')
    return render(request,'test.html',)
```

**models.py**

```
class Quizz(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ans1=models.CharField(max_length=20,default='')
    ans2=models.CharField(max_length=20,default='')
    ans3=models.CharField(max_length=20,default='')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'quizz'
```

Comment: ** quizz.ans1** only..in html page

Answer (score 1):

You forget to add in the request context.
views.py

```
def test(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        user = request.user
        ans1=request.POST['sky']
        ans2=request.POST['cricket']
        ans3=request.POST['river']
        x=Quizz.objects.create(user=user,ans1=ans1,ans2=ans2,ans3=ans3)
        x.save()
        return redirect('home')
    return render(request,'test.html', context={'data': x})
```